# Putty cannot register anything i type in, serial connection issue

Tags: keyboard, putty, modem, serial-port

I'm having trouble using putty to set up a serial connection using my 16 port GSM modem. I am using the correct baud rate, data bits and stop bits for my modem.

Just for reference I connected my GSM modem to my laptop using a USB 2.0 A male to a USB-B and all 16 ports shows up on my device manager, but after opening up the terminal PuTTY is not recognizing any of my keyboard strokes.

I think there must be an issue with the connection, but i cant figure out where the issue lies. Can anyone help?

Device manager:
[image: device manager]

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your putty connection settings? should be serial, the correct COM port, and I would try with 115200, type "AT" and hit enter....

Comment: I'm not familiar with accessing a modem via serial, but if it's not a plug-n-play setup _(e.g. the USB-to-Serial pins are connected via wires versus a header/USB port)_ check the Tx wire to ensure it's correctly wired.

Answer (score 1):

> **PuTTY is not recognizing any of my keyboard strokes.**

Normally, Any terminal emulator such as PuTTY doesn't display the keys you type. It only displays the data sent by the other end. So if the other end isn't echoing the keystrokes back to you, you won't see anything.

Have a play with `Settings`, `Terminal`, `Local Echo`, `Force On`. If you see double characters, turn it off.